# Changing the lein repl prompt text

Tags: clojure, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop

When I run `lein repl` I get a wonderful interactive REPL with the following prompt

```
user=>
```

I happen to use the lein repl on an application (as a console) and i'd love to have something like:

```
user(<environment>)=>

;; e.g. when run in production:
user(PRODUCTION)=>
```

When this is used to access the repl/console in an environment.

Comment: link to lein's :repl-options, see the :prompt key https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/sample.project.clj#L357

Comment: Those kind of questions underline the fact that Clojure is now an established production-ready enterprise language ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a production profile to your project.clj and specify a custom prompt function:

```
:profiles {:production
           {:repl-options
            {:prompt (fn [ns] (format "%s(PRODUCTION)=> " ns))}}}
```

Then `lein with-profile production repl`. I suppose you could do the same thing without a profile, but your prompt function would need to figure out what environment it's in. Maybe something like this:

```
:repl-options {:prompt (fn [ns] (format "%s(%s) => " ns (System/getenv "HOME")))}
```

You may also need to add `org.clojure/tools.nrepl` to your dependencies for this to work.

Comment: Perfect! I am lucky enough to have the specific environment on `env` so a quick call to `System/getenv` works like a charm.

Comment: `tools.nrepl` moved to `nrepl`: https://github.com/nrepl/nrepl